# Remap mouse button 8 ("browser forward") to mouse button 2 ("middle click") on RHEL

Tags: x11, mouse

What would be the proper way to remap mouse buttons on RHEL? xbindkeys doesn't seem to be available on my repos (not RHEL default, but enterprise custom repos). I guess I could install it on my own, but even then, I don't know how to create a proper xbindkeyssrc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only need simple button reassignment (as opposed to complex things like assigning commands to button combinations, or configuring different mice differently), the venerable [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) (a core X11 utility) can do the task. For example, to swap buttons 2 and 8 out of 12:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 11 12'
```

Arrange to run this command when your GUI session starts. How to do that depends on your desktop environment.